# Angularjs - how to access to one controller from other module angularjs (use typescript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

*// in engagement.component.ts:*

```
class EngagementMembersController {
         alphabetic: Array<string> = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
         constructor() {}

 export const EngagementSetupMember: IComponentOptions = {
    controller: EngagementMembersController,
    templateUrl: 'engagementMembers.component.html'
}
```

*// in topbar.moudel.ts:*

```
import {EngagementSetupMember} from './../engagement.component';
export const topBarMembersModule: string = angular
.module('topbar-members', [])
.controller(EngagementSetupMember.controller)
.component('topbarMemberComponant', {
    require: {
        controller: '^EngagementMembersController'
    },
    templateUrl: 'topBarMembers.component.html'
})
.name;
```

but when i use it, screen printed an error:

> vendor.js:36574 Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller
>   'EngagementMembersController', required by directive
>   'topbarMemberComponant', can't be found!

please help!

Comment: Could you also post the code for `EngagementMembersController`, and also show us how you are registering that controller (where you do `.component()` or `.controller()`)

Comment: yep, i edited it @HTom

Comment: Can you post the actual code for `EngagementMembersController`? Also, you seem to be registering that controller incorrectly. You need provide both a name and function/class for the controller.


Something like `.controller('EngagementMembersController ', EngagementSetupMember.controller)` would be more correct, assuming `EngagementSetupMember.controller` is a function or class.

Comment: i edited code for EngagementMembersController. The second argument accepts only one function , object or type any[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I must to call EngagementMembersController by another component before I could use:

```
require: {
    controller: '^EngagementMembersController'
},
```

in that case, i called in ui_router and it could be load